# Does Skorokhod's representation theorem work for continuous-time process?

Tags: probability

Quoting Wikipedia, Skorokhod's representation theorem states like this:

> Let $(\mu _{n})_{n\in \mathbb {N} }$ be a sequence of probability measures on a metric space $S$ such that $\mu _{n}$ converges weakly to some probability measure $\mu _{\infty }$ on $S$ as $
> n\to \infty$. Suppose also that the support of $\mu _{\infty }$ is separable. Then there exist $S$-valued random variables $(X_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}$ defined on a common probability space
> $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},\mathbf {P} )$ such that the law of $X_{n}$ is $\mu _{n}$ for all $n$ (including $n = \infty$) and such that $(X_{n})_{{n\in {\mathbb  {N}}}}$ converges to $X_{\infty }$,
> $\mathbf {P}$-almost surely.

My question: is there a continuous-time version of the above theorem? More precisely, does the following statement hold true?

> Let $(\mu _{t})_{t\geq 0}$ be a process of probability measures on a metric space $S$ such that $\mu _{t}$ converges weakly to some probability measure $\mu _{\infty }$ on $S$ as $
> t\to \infty$. Suppose also that the support of $\mu _{\infty }$ is separable. Then there exist $S$-valued stochastic process $(X_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ defined in a probability space
> $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},\mathbf {P} )$ such that the law of $X_{t}$ is $\mu _{t}$ for all $t$ (including $t = \infty$) and such that $(X_{t})_{{t\geq 0}}$ converges to $X_{\infty }$,
> $\mathbf {P}$-almost surely.

Comment: I suspect that this requires some extra hypotheses. At an absolute minimum, I think that you need to know that the map $t \mapsto \mu_t$ is measurable in the space of probability measures. I have no idea how one would prove this under that assumption, though. I would not be surprised if you could just repeat the proof of the discrete case if you assume continuity of $t \mapsto \mu_t$.

Comment: I find a reference which I'm not sure is sufficient: D. Blackwell and L. Dubins, An extension of Skorokhod’s almost sure representation theorem, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 89 (1983).